# ScrollView hide part of content

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a ScrollView, but a content's part is hidden :

[image]

Fragment here:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AccountConfigurationFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_go_back_main"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_input_server_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/text_input_user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_server_address"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_input_user_name"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch_notificate_hungry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:text="Notifier la faim"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/password_password"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch_thirst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:text="Notifier la soif"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_notificate_hungry"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switch_max_ap"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:checked="true"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:text="Notifier Point d'Actions max"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_thirst"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_go_back_main"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="106dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                app:iconTint="#ACACAC"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switch_max_ap" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_save"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/save"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_go_back_main" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is wrong with this fragment ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it with using `android:overScrollMode="never"` in your `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            android:overScrollMode="never">
```

Comment: Hello, part of my content is still hidden :(

Comment: It works with my test :) Watch my code snippet

Comment: Oh, crap ! I copied wrong fragment code in my question. Thanks for your response !